# SQL join between dates in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL.....I have one record from TABLE1:

```
PURCHASE_DATE
1/10/2023
```

And in TABLE2 I have a range of dates:

```
REQUIRED_DATE
1/5/2023
1/8/2023
1/11/2023
```

I want to do a join to TABLE2 where the required date was before purchase date. In this case I would get TABLE2 records with 1/5/2023 and 1/8/2023. I can easily do this with:

PURCHASE_DATE >= REQUIRED_DATE on my join clause. However I ONLY want the max of 1/8/2023 to return.

In my main query when I do a MAX(REQUIRED_DATE) I still get the 1/5/2023 and 1/8/2023

```
SELECT
TABLE1.BUYER
, TABLE1.PURCHASE_ORDER
, TABLE1.PURCHASE_DATE
, TABLE2.REQUESTED_DATE
, MAX(TABLE2.REQUIRED_DATE) REQUIRED_DATE
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN
TABLE2
ON TABLE1.PURCHASE_DATE >= TABLE2.REQUIRED_DATE
GROUP BY
TABLE1.BUYER
, TABLE1.PURCHASE_ORDER
, TABLE1.PURCHASE_DATE
, TABLE2.REQUESTED_DATE
```

Comment: For starters which database system do you have

Comment: The columns in your SQL don’t match the sample data and the sample data seems to have a number of typos in it. Please update your question with accurate table definitions and data - and provide the result you want to achieve based on your sample data

Comment: Remove , TABLE2.REQUESTED_DATE f Om the group by and select

Comment: I actually need that requested_date

Comment: There can be many `table2` rows per `table1` row. For the `required_date` you have told us which you want to pick. But you haven't told us which `requested_date` you want to pick. And again: what is your DBMS? It is unlikely you get a proper answer as long as you keep this a secret.

Comment: Oracle sql...i need the requested date that is listed on the max required date

Comment: Sample data in DB fiddle would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a lateral join (`CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY`). As you had an outer join, you probably want an `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT
  t1.buyer,
  t1.purchase_order,
  t1.purchase_date,
  t2.requested_date,
  t2.required_date
FROM table1 t1
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2.required_date <= t1.purchase_date
  ORDER BY required_date DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from table2
where required_date <= (select purchase_date from table1)
order by required_date desc
fetch next 1 rows only
```